# How to use cordova sqlite plugin with Ionic 5 app in React?

Tags: reactjs, sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework, capacitor

I have followed the documentation  [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/sqlite), installed cordova-sqlite-storage, @ionic-native/sqlite, and @ionic-core, and have the following code on app.tsx.

```
import { SQLite, SQLiteObject } from '@ionic-native/sqlite/';

function AppSession(props:any){
...


useEffect(()=>{

  SQLite.create({
    name: 'data.db',
    location: 'default'
  }).then((result) => {
    console.log("DONE");
    console.log(result);
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log("ERROR");
    console.log(err);
  });
},[])
```

After that I run the app on the browser with the command **ionic serve** but I am getting the error **Cannot read property 'then' of undefined** for SQLite.create(...).

I haven't found much on the documentation or the forums. 
What am I doing wrong? What is the right way to use the plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is probably that you're running the app in the browser. If you build it for a device, I imagine it would work. Have a look at [this repo](https://github.com/alex-steinberg/ionic-react-sqlite-example) to see a working example of a simple app using the Cordova SQLite plugin with Ionic React and Capacitor.

Comment: You're right. I guess it only works on devices. Is there a way I can mock/substitute the behavior of the plugin for development? It would be a pain having to build the app to some device each time I need to test my work

Comment: The @ionic/storage API is a neat abstraction to store key.value pairs on whatever storage is available be it SQLite, indexeddb or local storage: https://ionicframework.com/docs/building/storage